# Where can I found some documentation about commit process?

Tags: solr

I would like to know where I can found some documentation about the commit process. I've looked on the Solr Website but I didn't find what I'm looking for.

I know that a commit make a change (add, update or delete) visible in the index. But what really happens when you call the commit fonction ?

When you add a document, is it written in a segment file ? or is it keeped in RAM ?
Does a commit open Writer to write in the segment ? Does a commit merge segments or not ?

Where can I find informations about the commit process and adding document process ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some good links that talk about the commit and optimize processes.

- [Solr Commit and Optimize Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137607/solr-commit-and-optimize-questions)
- [Lucene Core - IndexWriter.commit()](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_1/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#commit%28%29)
- [Solr CommitWithin](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommitWithin)
- [Choosing Solr/Lucene Commit Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907500/choosing-a-solr-lucene-commit-strategy)

Comment: Thank you Paige, the "Lucene Core - IndexWriter.commit()" link is what I was looking for. I've already visited the other links.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

1. download solr and run the example, with remote debugging enabled

   java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8765 -jar start.jar
2. debug as remote application from eclipse
3. add break points, such as SolrCore::execute
4. add document with post.sh or post.jar
5. follow the debugger and read the java docs and code

With one hour or so, you'll get clear about all these questions.