# Solr: do we need commit=true query when we have autoCommit in SolrConfig?

Tags: solr

I'm new to Solr and unsure do we need commit=true in push query when we have autoCommit  in SolrConfig???

Here is QA about autoCommit that partial help me to understand autoCommit:

[Choosing a solr/lucene commit strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907500/choosing-a-solr-lucene-commit-strategy/3916876)

But now need clarification, for this part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need it if you want to make sure your updates get picked up sooner than the autocommit in solrconfig.xml will. If you don't have the urgency, just dont.

Also notice that you can use commitWithin=X that is not as aggressive as commit=true